# What might be the reasons of angular getting http error status code 0 Unknown Error (in my case)?

Tags: angular, nestjs, http-error

Recently, a bug appeared in the angular application.

Generaly it works like that:

1. User clicks button.
2. Angular triggers method, which do a few things, then make request to my NestJS api.
3. API generates PDF file and then returns it as a buffer.
4. Angular receives PDF file from response as blob, then displays it in a new tab to user.

Here is the bug description:

About 1% of requests returns error. About 99% of requests works totally fine.
However API always receives request, then always correctly returns PDF buffer (no error in logs, it says that response code status is 200). So angular correctly sends request, but sometimes doesn't catch the response (???).

I could never reproduce such error/behavior, only users can :D

Here is the error object, that Angular receives:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "Unknown Error",
    "url": "https://[my_hidden_url]/multirep/offer?OfferNo=448589",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://[my_hidden_url]/multirep/offer?OfferNo=448589: 0 Unknown Error",
    "error": {
        "isTrusted": true
    }
}
```

Here is the end of my API endpoint (maybe there is something wrong with response settings?):

```
const PDFBuffer = await this.mreport.generateOfferPDFAndGetBuffer(pagesReadyToMerge);

console.log('PDF Buffer length and PDFBuffer type: ', PDFBuffer.length, typeof PDFBuffer);

res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-Length': PDFBuffer.length,
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Expires': 0,
});
  
res.send(PDFBuffer);
```

Here is the part of triggered angular method (this line catches error):

```
offerPdf = await this.service.getOfferPDF(`https://[my_hidden_url]/multirep/offerOfferNo=${offerNo}`);
```

Here is the service method that makes request to my api:

```
getOfferPDF(url: string): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res) {
          resolve(res);
        } else {
          reject(res);
        }
      },
      error => {
        reject(error);
      },
    );
  });
}
```

According to my research of "0 Unknown Error" it can be related with:

- incorrect CORS configuration (in NestJS I use the code below)

```
const server = express();
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, 
    new ExpressAdapter(server)
);
app.enableCors();
```

- AdBlock (couldn't reproduce error this way)
- Slow/No internet connection (couldn't reproduce error this way)

Additional information:

The error object I provided above comes from database (Angular error handling system catched and saved it there) so I don't really know what displays in browser console as error - it might be different than status 0.

Comment: The issue's still not solved...